# Line 4:27: 'component' is missing in props validation react/prop-types

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react and when i am trying to run the code this is the error i am getting

Line 4:27:  'component' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...restOfProps }) {
const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')
console.log('this', isAuthenticated)

return (
<Route
  {...restOfProps}
  render={(props) => (isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Navigate to="/Login" />)}
/>
)
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

i am using latest version of react will apricate any help

Comment: You probably want to use props.children?if so , just change component to children in the function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function ProtectedRoute({ Component, ...restOfProps }) {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated");
  console.log("this", isAuthenticated);

  return (
    <Route
      {...restOfProps}
      render={(props) => (isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Navigate to="/Login" />)}
    />
  );
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function ProtectedRoute({ component, ...restOfProps }) {
const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')
console.log('this', isAuthenticated)

return (
<Route
  {...restOfProps}
  render={(props) => (isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Navigate to="/Login" />)}
/>
)
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

Comment: still same error. Also it does not define Components

Comment: @AIDJ  if possible  please share screenshot

Comment: https://ibb.co/nPLSBgm

Comment: what is your file format ? =>    js , ts , jsx or tsx

Comment: its => ProtectedRoute.js

Comment: i post another answer try please